# ManagedResource Warnings in Solr

Tags: solr

I'm getting two warnings in my Apache Solr Admin logs:

WARN-ManagedResource-No stored data found for /rest/managed

WARN-ManagedResource-No registered observers for /rest/managed

I can't seem to find what these mean or how to resolve them.

Answer (score 0):

I was also trying to sort out the same problem.

You can gain some knowledge about this on http://searchhub.org/2014/03/31/introducing-solrs-restmanager-and-managed-stop-words-and-synonyms/

Although it is a very long article but some of the abstracts like quoted below suggests me to ignore these warnings.

> Solr components register as **observers** of managed resources and the
>   RestManager is responsible for initializing managed resources